# Unable to call function declared in the same parent function (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

**The problem is solved. It has nothing to do with the function, but a CSS precedence issue.**

I declared a function called alternateTableColor() inside the anonymous function assigned to window.onload. This function alternates the color of a table on the webpage. When it's called without being nested to any other functions, it works fine. But when it's nested in another function declared in the same environment, it does not work. Can you help?

```js
function my$(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function deleteTr(oTr) {
  oTr.parentNode.removeChild(oTr);
}
  let currentId = 2;
  let oTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  let aAs = oTable.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('a');

  function alternateTableColor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < oTable.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
      if (i % 2) {
        oTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
      } else {
        oTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
      }
    }
  }
  alternateTableColor();
  // add event to existing delete button
  for (let i = 0; i < aAs.length; i++) {
    aAs[i].onclick = function() {
      deleteTr(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    }
  }
  // add event to create button
  my$('create-entry').onclick = function() {
    // add all html data to a data array
    let data = [];
    data.push(++currentId);
    data.push(my$('add-name').value);
    data.push(my$('add-age').value);
    data.push('<a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a>');

    // create a <tr> element
    let oTr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      let oTd = document.createElement('td');
      oTd.innerHTML = data[i];
      oTr.appendChild(oTd);
    }
    oTable.tBodies[0].appendChild(oTr);

    // add click event to <a>Delete</a>
    let oA = oTr.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    oA.onclick = function() {
      deleteTr(this.parentNode.parentNode);
    }
  };
  // add event to search button
  my$('search-query').onclick = function() {
    alternateTableColor();
    let aQueries = my$('query').value.split(' ');
    console.log(aQueries);
    for (let i = 0; i < oTable.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
      let source = (oTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[1]).innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      for (let j = 0; j < aQueries.length; j++) {
        let target = aQueries[j].toLowerCase();
        if (source.search(target) != -1) {
          oTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[1].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  my$('clear-color').onclick = alternateTableColor;
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}

thead tr {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px double black;
}

/* tbody > :nth-child(even){
            background-color: lightgrey;
        } */

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.data-input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.data-input::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

.box {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.search {
  /* float: right; */
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#query {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% - 106px);
}

#search-query,
#create-entry {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 2px;
  width: 100px;
}

.ul-input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: inset;
  border-bottom-color: initial;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.ul-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ul-input::placeholder,
.ul-input {
  text-align: center;
}

.ul-input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="data-input">
    <div class="add-new">
      <label for="add-name">Name: </label><input type="text" id="add-name" class="ul-input" placeholder="Enter name" />
      <label for="add-age">Age: </label><input type="number" id="add-age" class="ul-input" placeholder="Enter age" />
      <input type="button" id="create-entry" value="Create" />
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" id="query" class="ul-input" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
      <input type="button" id="search-query" value="Search" /><br>
      <input type="button" id="clear-color" value="Clear Color" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>June</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Added HTML code. Thanks for calling it out.

Comment: I added additional code that colors the table. If I reset, the color does not go back.

Comment: I reposted the whole script. Sorry, was trying to shorten the code, but left some traces.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is reproducible now :)

Comment: Unfortunately I think this boils down to a typo error. Check your console: on page load, you will see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null` pointing to the line `my$('clear-color').onclick = alternateTableColor;`. But there is no element with an ID of `clear-color`; the ID of that button is `reset-color` instead. Fix that, and it works as expected https://jsfiddle.net/xyca5dno/

Comment: In my full code, I actually supplied the id of "clear-color". I edited "clear-color" to "reset-color" when I first posted the question, but it's not in my actual code.

Comment: I tested it in Chrome and Edge, but both have the same issue.

Comment: The TRs still look to be having their colors properly alternated whenever I create or delete new TRs.

Comment: I figured it out! When the color is altered by the search function, the color attribute is added to the <td>, but then resetting only applies to <tr>, which then gets overwritten by the new <td> color.. Sorry for the trouble. And thanks for being patient!!

Comment: This is the first time you mentioned that the problem was with the *search* button resulting in items remaining highlighted...

Answer (score 0):

Javascript scopes variables by functions.

```
function a() {  
  var b = 1;
  function c() {
  }
}
// b is undefined
// c is also undefined
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Description

Note that `function c() {}` is equivalent to `var c = function () {};`

```
function a () {
 function b() {
    console.log('b');
 }
 function c() {
    console.log('c');
    b();
 }

 c();
}

a(); // prints c then b
```

Comment: I don't think that's it. The code is more like this: function b() and function c() are both declared within a(), but c() cannot call b() successfully.

Comment: `alternateTableColor` *is* scoped properly in OP's code, though.

Comment: My point was that inside c it can successfully call b - the order doesn't matter.
Which even re-reading your comment above is how I understand what you're asking.
Maybe if you rephrase the question you'll get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call function your intentional position.

```
window.onload = function() {
    let oTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    window.alternateTableColor = function(){
        for (let i = 0; i < oTable.tBodies[0].rows.length; i++) {
            if(i % 2) {
                oTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightgrey';
            } else {
                oTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].style.backgroundColor = '';
            }
        }
    }
    alternateTableColor(); // it works here

    let oBtn = document.getElementById('reset-color');
    oBtn.onclick = function(){;
        console.log('testing'); // console.log successfully
        alternateTableColor(); // you can call!!!!
    }
}
```

It's JavaScript's lexical scope.
You can study this https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/

Comment: I know how lexical scope works... Which is exactly why I'm posting the question because it doesn't work here.

Comment: @CarolJin trigger onClick handler's context is window. however alternateTableColor's context is onload handler's this. So you do bind(this) or window context define